# Find rows with MySQL where column has values 'n' AND others values

Tags: mysql

Consider the tables `order`, `order_line` and `product`.

`order_line` has columns `order_id` and `product_id`.

I want to find the orders that have order_line with `product_category` 1 AND other `product_categories`. Example of the order_line results:

```
 id | order_id | product_category
----+----------+-------------------
 6  |     5    |    1
 7  |     5    |    2
```

Category 1 MUST exist, as well as other categories.

I tried the following, but it does not help, it's probably a fault in my logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM order_line
WHERE
 product_category = 1 AND
 order_id IN (
   SELECT order_id
   FROM order_line
   WHERE
    product_category != 1
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the other categories as well as the "1", use two `exists`:

```
SELECT ol.*
FROM order_line ol
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from order_line ol2 where ol2.order_id = ol.order_id and product_category = 1) AND
      EXISTS (select 1 from order_line ol2 where ol2.order_id = ol.order_id and product_category <> 1) ;
```

This is almost a direct translation of your problem statement.

Note:  If you just want the orders that have this condition, I would approach that using a `group by`:

```
select ol.order_id, group_concat(distinct product_category) as categories
from orderline ol
group by ol.order_id
having sum(product_category = 1) > 0 and
       sum(product_category <> 1) > 0;
```

But the first version gives all the order detail.

Comment: That's it. I don't know how I forgot 'exists', thanks!